# Transfer data from one table to another table with hidden columns

Tags: jquery

I want to transfer data from one table to another table. In below coding it is working properly. My problem is - some columns in the `.src-table` table are hidden. In the `.target-table` I don't want to hide these columns. It should be displayed. It would be helpful if any experienced help.

```js
$(function () {
  $(document).on("click", "#submit", function () {
    var getSelectedRows = $(".src-table input:checked").parents("tr").clone();
    $(".target-table tbody").append(getSelectedRows);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Source table</h3>
<table class="src-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th hidden="hidden">Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td hidden="hidden">Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td hidden="hidden">Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit"> 
<h3> Target table </h3>
<table class="target-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `hidden` attribute from the descendant elements before appending them to the DOM:

```js
$(function () {
  $(document).on("click", "#submit", function () {
    var getSelectedRows = $(".src-table input:checked").parents("tr").clone();
    
    // remove the "hidden" attribute
    getSelectedRows.find('[hidden="hidden"]').each(function (i, el) {
      $(el).removeAttr('hidden');
    });
    
    $(".target-table tbody").append(getSelectedRows);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Source table</h3>
<table class="src-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th hidden="hidden">Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td hidden="hidden">Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td hidden="hidden">Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit"> 
<h3> Target table </h3>
<table class="target-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```